# How to check for a value in a column and drop/proceed read (select) on a table using sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table: LoadResults with the columns: load, incLoad & incKeys

case 1:

```
load    incLoad     incKeys
Full    Full          11
Delta   Delta         12
Delta   Delta         13
Delta   Delta         17
Full    Full          19
Full    Full          15
Delta   Delta         16
```

The column `incKeys` contains the keys(incremental data) is to be moved. We maintain a metadata table: `MetaLoad` where we keep the last moved `incKey` from the previous loads of every table so that we can use that key (from table: `MetaLoad`) and get the new incremental Keys from `LoadResults` table using the below query:

```
select incKeys from schema.LoadResults where incKeys > metaLoadKey
```

-- I am able to get the value of metaLoadKey using code.

Before querying the table: `LoadResults` for incremental keys, I need to check if the type of load in either of the columns: `load, incLoad` is `FULL`.
If it is FULL in either of the columns, then I have to drop the read on the table. If not, I need to read all values of the colum: `incKeys` (select incKeys)
case 2:

```
load    incLoad     incKeys
Delta   Delta         11
Delta   Delta         12
Delta   Delta         13
Delta   Delta         17
Delta   Delta         19
```

If it only has "Delta", my output should contain all the `incKeys`.

I am unable to think of a logic to implement this using a SQL query. Could anyone let me know how can I frame a query to perform the function I mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using nested SQL statements. This code will show your records only when there are all incLoad and load equal to 'Delta', otherwise not a single result would be shown.

```
    select incKeys from schema.LoadResults where incKeys > metaLoadKey AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.LoadResults where not incLoad='Delta' or not load='Delta')=0;
```

The nested statement acts as a condition and makes sure that COUNT of entries having not Delta as incLoad or load is equal to zero.

Comment: No. I should drop the whole read if there is an entry for "FULL" in the columns: Load & IncLoad

Comment: Edited my answer. Your question is more clear now. This is according to the assumption that 'no read' means returning no result.

Comment: Excatly. There shouldn't be any result or the select operation should be dropped if there is a record "FULL"